# Which mantra in sri vidya school is most suitable for manifesting wealth?

Tags: mantras, sri-vidya

At high level all mantras are same as they led to same goals. But individual manyra do leave their effect. Which mantra in sri vidya schoolnis best suited fir manifesting wealth in life. Thanks

Comment: @Saurabh better discuss in chat room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53977/agama-and-tantra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sri**  mean **prosperity**. So, Sri VidyA, as the name itself suggests, is bound to give wealth among other things, if worshipped as prescribed and after initiation.

In the KubjikA Tantram (from the VishnukrAntA group of Tantras), Lord Shiva defines Sri VidyA in just one Shloka as follows:

> [Lord Shiva said]
>
> **SridAtri cha sada vidyA srividya parikirtitA** |
>   Nirguna cha mahAdevi shodashi parikirtitA ||
>
> Since the VidyA gives prosperity always, it is so called. And since
>   the Great Goddess is Nirguna (impersonal), she is known as Shodashi.

So, all forms of Sri VidyA will give prosperity, wealth. It is actually mentioned in scriptures as the giver of Bhukti and Mukti both.

So, irrespective of what the Mantra is (like say Panchadashi, Shodashi, Mahashodashi, Dipani, SwapnAvati, Madhumati, Saubhagya Mantra or any other) all will give prosperity besides bestowing other things.

Comment: Rick can you please explain what are Dipani, SwapnAvati, Madhumati, Saubhagya Mantra ?

Comment: Explaining means I have to give u those Mantras.. I can give as they are mentioned in Tantrasara.. but at the same time it's stated that such secret Mantras from the Tantras should not be revealed publicly.. so i am reluctant.. hope u don't mind? @Saurabh